# XPath - How to select node that has only 1 class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

For xpath on c#, how can I select a node by class where the node only has that 1 class?

For example, if I had this:

```
<span class="red blue"></span>
<span class="red"></span>
```

The xpath expression given "red" will only return the second node.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this XPath:

```
//span[normalize-space(@class) = 'red']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to select all `span` elements that have a @class that contains `red` and you are sure that the string `red` will not appear elsewhere in the `@class` use this in XPATH 1.0:

```
//span[contains(@class,'red')]
```

If red may appear within a different class (like say `centered`) you'll need to get more complex

```
//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' red ')]
```

If you can use XPATH 2.0, you can account for both cases like this:

```
//span[tokenize(@class,'\s+')[. eq 'red']]
```